# Script tag is loading from file:/// instead of http://

Tags: javascript, html, http

I am working with a simple HTML test page. I am opening it with Chrome version 40.0.2214.115. In order to test the code, I am loading a js file from my workplace.

However, the file which I loaded tries to load other js files through script tags, but does not specify http:// . This causes an error in the console, as it defaults to the file:/// protocol and is unable to load file://the/restof/theurl.js

I downloaded the file locally, and loaded it from there, adding http:// to all url's, so it would ACTUALLY use the HTTP protocol.

This worked fine. However, those links load OTHER files that also do not specify http://

Is there any way I can have the browser imply http:// to unspecified script tags, and avoid downloading and editing EVERY file just to test a small HTML page?

Comment: Yes, by using a local server like MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/. This will allow you to run as if its on the `http` protocol. Otherwise you are looking at hacks since your pages aren't intended to run on the `file://` protocol anyway, they're meant to run on the internet. If they are meant to run on the `file://` protocol, you should make all files locally avaialble as theres no guarantee of internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to prevent problems like this is to actually use a very small server (like something provided by node.js or the like or lighttpd).

Obviously your files are not supposed to be delivered via the plain `file` protocol, so you should just use a http server. That way you can be sure they work as intended and you don't have to fiddle around with your browser on a deeper level.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch chrome with the below flags this should work. Obviously not possible for production environments, but for testing it should be okay.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a simple local file server. If you are unsure how to, since you are developing in JavaScript, you can easily create a simple file server using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) which written in JS using simple middleware like [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static).